# Formatting by deleting arrays by indexes Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, slice

I want to delete all the other arrays within `list_` that are not listed in the `keep` array. So the new `list_` function would consist of `[402.152008,435.790985,423.204987]`

```
keep = np.arange(5, 8, 1)
list_= np.array([457.334015,424.440002,394.795990,408.903992,398.821014,402.152008,435.790985,423.204987,411.574005,
404.424988,399.519989,377.181000,375.467010,386.944000,383.614990,375.071991,359.511993,328.865997,
320.510010,330.079010,336.187012,352.940002,365.026001,361.562012,362.299011,378.549011,390.414001,
400.869995,394.773010,382.556000])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works simply by indexing `list_` with the elements in `keep`:

```
In [20]: list_[keep]
Out[20]: array([402.152008, 435.790985, 423.204987])
```